# How does form template work in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, dry

If we create the default scaffold in Rails, both the `edit.html.erb` and `new.html.erb` render the same `_form.html.erb` within. Both create forms with certain similarities and differences.

Such as:

- Both create `<form method="post" ...>`
- The submit buttons have different texts `<input value='Create model'
  ..` and `<input value='New model' ..`

My questions:

1. How does the conditional rendering work?
2. How to display form elements conditionally? E.g., show this
   `<input>` only if it is called via `edit.html.erb`, but do not show
   it if called via `new.html.erb`.
3. If the method in q.2 possible, is it the right way? We are reusing
   code instead of replicating the form all over again, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're following RESTful conventions, the differences you see between edit and new are based on the state of the object that you pass to the form. Rails can tell the difference between a new object and one that has been persisted by using the `#new_record?` method.

```
Model.new.new_record? # => true
Model.first.new_record? # => false
```

In your `#new` controller action, you probably have something like:

```
@model = Model.new
```

In your `#edit` action, you probably have something like:

```
@model = Mode.find(params[:id])
```

This `@model` object is then passed to the form, which handles the conditional logic internally. Another difference in the form you should notice is that the `#edit` version has a hidden input field that tells the server to use the `PUT` HTTP method.

**Update**

It looks like Rails actually uses the [persisted? method](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/beba8267c96a3dbc1f505ecc099dbf14db8dde4c/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb#L1419) internally as opposed to new_record?. The difference is that persisted? checks whether the record has been deleted. Otherwise, they are identical (but opposite)

Comment: The first part of my response should answer your second question about how to add conditional logic, just check if the object is a new record or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as it:

In new.html.erb:
`<%= render :partial =>'form', :locals => {:action => 'new', :f => f } %>`

In edit.html.erb:
`<%= render :partial =>'form', :locals => {:action => 'edit', :f => f } %>`

In _form.html.erb:
`if action == 'new'`
or
`if action == 'edit'`

Also you can send other parameters by `:locals` such as `:show_mobile => false`.

Comment: If rails already knows the action while rendering the `_form.html.erb`, there should be a way to leverage that, instead of passing in a parameter manually..

Comment: Yes.But sometimes we should do a little different things between different pages.So the parameter is necessary.Is there any good method?